# How to install "devtools" package in R 3.4.0?

Tags: r, devtools

Recently I've faced a problem, connected with the installation of `devtools` package in R 3.4.0.  When I type:

```
install.packages("devtools")
```

The following message appears:

> One or more of the packages that will be updated by this installation are currently loaded. Restarting R prior to updating these packages is
> strongly recommended.
>
> RStudio can restart R and then automatically continue the installation after restarting (all work and data will be preserved
> during the restart)
>
> Do you want to restart R prior to installing?

After I press "Yes", restart of the current RStudio session takes place, and the process of `devtools` package installation begins. But the installation process doesn't come to its end, and, finally, the message about the necessity of restarting current RStudio session, described above, appears.

Comment: Did you try opening a fresh R session, and try to install before any library calls?

Comment: ps your R version is @3 years old -- you should update

Comment: Also make sure you close *all* your RStudio sessions. Another session with the package loaded can block the update.

Comment: What operating system are you on (if on Windows, you might need Rtools)? Your Rstudio might be restoring a session at restart. You should check it off and try again https://community.rstudio.com/t/defaults-of-saving-and-restoring-workspace/939/2

Comment: Yes, I did, The problem remained.

Comment: I use Windows 8.1

Comment: I have an already installed Rtools35 pack, but it doesn't change anything. Do you think  the sense of this problem is in the old version of RStudio, installed on my computer?

Comment: @Maxim; are you getting any messages or errors? It is certainly possible that some dependency requires a more recent version of R. It is easy to upgrade; just click through the relevant links https://cloud.r-project.org/ -- or I think this may be the direct link for windows https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/ (ps note that the programming language you are using is R; Rstudio just provides an IDE / wrapper that makes it a wee bit nicer to use interactively)

Comment: @user20650, will the upgrade of R lead to deletetion of unsaved data or scripts from RStudio? Will this process influence R data anyhow?

Comment: I' not sure. I do not think that reinstalling r would delete .rds and .rdata files from your working directory but better safe than sorry. Explicitly save all scripts and workspaces that you want.

Comment: @user20650, should I delete the old RStudio version before installing the new one?

Comment: Not necessary. On windows you can have multiple versions of R. And for Rstudio I have never uninstalled it before upgrading.So the steps I would take is 1) [install R](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/) 2) [install Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) and **follow instructions to add it to your path** 3) [install rstudio](https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/windows/RStudio-1.3.1056.exe) 4) open R in Rstudio and install all the packages you regularly use.

Answer (score 0):

this step-wise process works for me on Ubuntu Bionic 18.04 with R-3.4.4:

```
apt-get -y build-dep libcurl4-gnutls-dev
apt-get -y install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
wget https://github.com/r-lib/memoise/archive/refs/tags/v.1.1.0.tar.gz
mv v.1.1.0.tar.gz memoise-1.1.0.tar.gz
R CMD INSTALL memoise-1.1.0.tar.gz
wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/tibble/tibble_1.3.0.tar.gz
R CMD INSTALL tibble_1.3.0.tar.gz
wget https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/archive/refs/tags/devtools-0.5.tar.gz
R CMD INSTALL devtools-0.5.tar.gz
wget https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/archive/refs/tags/v1.4.tar.gz
mv v1.4.tar.gz devtools-1.4.tar.gz
R CMD INSTALL devtools-1.4.tar.gz
wget https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/archive/refs/tags/v1.11.1.tar.gz
mv v1.11.1.tar.gz devtools-1.11.1.tar.gz
R CMD INSTALL devtools-1.11.1.tar.gz
wget https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/archive/refs/tags/v1.13.6.tar.gz
mv  v1.13.6.tar.gz devtools-1.13.6.tar.gz
R CMD INSTALL devtools-1.13.6.tar.gz
```

Comment: This is both irrelevant (as the OP was on Windows) and not needed less as `sudo apt install r-cran-devtools` get you devtools (and, say, [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u) gets you _every_ CRAN package as a binary, directly from R, on Ubuntu LTS 20.04 or 22.04.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  It is (to me at still) still more of a comment than an answer as we all know full well from 25 years of CRAN that a package published there worked _at the time under the tools then used_ so yes, _every_ CRAN package current or archived will build if you give it all its build requirements.  It is a well curated repository.  But I suppose an illustration never hurts even if to a three year old question.

Comment: I think what is really missing is a way to automatically keep tryiing to install previous version of a package until you hit one which succeeds. It is clear that some old enough will work. I am not an R programmer so it is hard to navigate through. And the MRAN thing is shutdown, at least does not cver Ubuntu Bionic anymore. See https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/2534 and https://github.com/r-lib/remotes/issues/717 .

Comment: Bionic is seriously outdated. If you want "fast, easy, reliable" look at my [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u) which offers all of CRAN (!!) as Ubuntu binaries (!!) for both focal (20.04) and jammy (22.04) via full integration with `apt` from R.  You just say `install.packages("tidyverse")`, say, and 20 seconds later 100 packages with all dependencies installed.  Fast, easy, reliable.